# pygame window closes immediatly after opening up

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
#initialize the screen
pygame.init()

#create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((80, 600))

#tile and icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.quit():
            running = False
```

my pygame window closes as soon as it opens and then it displays the error pygame.error: video system not initialized. i use the community version of visual studio 2019.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) invokes the quit method and uninitialize all pygame modules. You have to evaluate if the event type attribute is equal the constant `pygame.QUIT` (see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)):

<s>`if event.type == pygame.quit():`</s>

```py
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```